# "to ensue" : usage questions

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Is there an active form to "to ensue" ? I'm familiar with constructions like "The fire started, chaos ensued".

1. Can one write "The fire ensued chaos" or "The fire ensued by chaos" ? If not, which verb can replace "ensue" here ?
2. Does "to ensue" imply a causation effect ? Or can I write "After friday, saturday will ensue"

Comment: Ensue means to follow. To happen afterwards or as a result of (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ensue)

Comment: In 1) the transitive verb [**ensure**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ensure) can be used. It is a different word, not another form of **ensue**. It won't work in 2) though.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what ensue means, my question is regarding the correctness of its usage in other ways that the most common form which seems to "A happened, B ensued".

Comment: @C4 I believe Smock did answer that question: By the nature of the word, it is follow or happen after. "The fire was ensued by chaos" is fine, but it means "The fire was followed by chaos". It seems odd to say that Saturday will ensure Friday, since the definition Smock has used (which is correct) says that ensue means *especially* as a result of, therefore it it will always naturally feel more like it should be used to imply cause and effect.

Comment: Actually, there *is* a transitive verb [*ensue*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ensued) that means ": to strive to attain : PURSUE // I wander, seeking peace, and *ensuing* it." But the meaning is different than in the question—even though, syntactically, it almost fits into the example sentences. You need to clarify the *exact* meaning you want here. Do you really mean *follows* (as a non-verb, but looking for a different word that means that verbally)—or does the sense of *ensue* as in "strive to attain" work (albeit figuratively)?

Comment: Note that neither meaning implies causality. If you're talking about causality, you need to find a different word.

Comment: I was thinking of the intransitive verb, since I was not aware of the transitive meaning. 

Looking up transitive versus intranstitive also helped a lot, and I think at this point I have the answers I was looking for.

I'm sorry if I've been unclear, it's not easy explaining exactly my question when it was unclear for me too ! ^^